# Python web scraping log in with facebook account

Tags: python, facebook, authentication, web

I want to log in to my library in Shazam using python. Although I have seen more or less how to access a website using log in credentials, I don't know how to do this if you log in with Facebook account. I located the Facebook API key as it is shown in the picture [image: api key] but I have no idea how to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from time import sleep 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  
  
usr=input('Enter Email Id:')  
pwd=input('Enter Password:')  
  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()) 
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/') 
print ("Opened facebook") 
sleep(1) 
  
username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email') 
username_box.send_keys(usr) 
print ("Email Id entered") 
sleep(1) 
  
password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('pass') 
password_box.send_keys(pwd) 
print ("Password entered") 
  
login_box = driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton') 
login_box.click() 
  
print ("Done") 
input('Press anything to quit') 
driver.quit() 
print("Finished")
```